# Proper way of encrypting/decryption JSON to/from disk?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, encryption, cryptography

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
```

Encryption:

```
const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes256', 'password');
let encrypted = cipher.update(JSON.stringify(this.state.data), 'utf8', 'hex');
encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
fs.writeFileSync('asdf.enc', encrypted);
```

Decryption:

```
const decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes256', 'password');
let contents = fs.readFileSync('asdf.enc', 'utf8');
let decrypted = decipher.update(contents, 'hex', 'utf8');
decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
let data = JSON.parse(decrypted);
```

However, I'm not sure if this is correct, because I couldn't find any code examples doing this (encrypting a JSON object and saving it to disk in a file).

It seems to be rather brittle (uses stringify, arbitrary hex encoding, and errors out if I perform the operation twice). Also, I'm not sure what the `cipher/decipher.final()` is doing. The piping examples don't use that but I'm not sure how to use piping here.

(Also, the files are really tiny so I think I'm okay with sync)

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare: bcrypt and AES do two completely different things.

Comment: Seems OK in my shallow view. Doesn't use authenticated encryption and for ciphertext hex is not very efficient, but otherwise. You may want to familiarize yourself with the password -> key derivation and possibly adjust the parameters (especially the work factor involved). Note that SO is for specific questions only; you should post working code to codereview.SE instead (read their FAQ first).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: Hi, thanks. Would you recommend `latin1` or `base64` instead? Also, I'm not sure what authenticated encryption is. Is that using [this?](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_setaad_buffer) I'm not sure how to apply it in this scenario. Also isn't KDF hashes separate from AES encryption? I didn't know you could increase the work factor for encryption.

Comment: base64 if you require text, otherwise use binary. Files usually can contain binary. AES itself doesn't handle passwords, see the `createCipher` method for details: the crypto module uses EVP_BytesToKey with one iteration by default (!).

Comment: Oh, and that AAD is just to add additional authenticated data. You should select GCM mode encryption during cipher creation.

Comment: Ah, this is all a bit over my head at the moment. I'll have to really look into this stuff later, or find a tutorial explaining best practices for doing this sort of thing.